# How to only restart one service in docker

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to start 3 services in docker-compose.yml

```
service1:
    image: <image-for service1>

service2:
    image: <image-for service1>

tomcatservice:
    image: tomcat:8.0.20-jre8
    depends_on:
      - service1
      - service2
    volumes:
     - ./target/myapp.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapp/myapp.war
    expose:
      - "8080"
    links:
      - service1
      - service2
```

this i am want to restart only tomcatservice with:

- latest maven build of my app code
- no changes in other 2 services so nothing needs to be done for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've updated `./target/myapp.war`, you just need to `docker-compose restart tomcatservice` to restart the service.

If you have changed the service at all in `docker-compose.yml`, you can instead do `docker-compose up -d tomcatservice` to rebuild it and restart it.